# How can I covert sqlachemy query into list object?

Tags: flask

hi guys I am trying to convert my query into object but I am getting this error " 'User' object is not iterable"

Below are my codes.

```py
@app.route('/users')
def users():
 
    rows = db.session.query(User).first(); 
    for row in rows:
        data.append(list(row))# data.append([x for x in row])  
    return jsonify(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have for querying

```py
rows = db.session.query(User).first();
```

selects the first object found and returns it, else returns `None` as per [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.first)

if there are multiple rows you are trying to query, use the `.all()` function as per [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.all)

```py
data = []
rows = db.session.query(User).all(); 
for row in rows:
    data.append(row)
return jsonify(data)
```

this will fetch all the users and add it to the list

Comment: shoaib30 Im now getting this error "TypeError: Object of type User is not JSON serializable"

Comment: @KelvinJones that would be outside the scope of this question, look into serializing objects in python [Flask jsonify a list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411497/flask-jsonify-a-list-of-objects)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this buy using flask mashmallow

```
ma = Marshmallow(app)

    enter code here

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(200),nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(200),nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(200),nullable=False)
  


class UserSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        # Fields to expose
        fields = ("email", "password","name")
     # Smart hyperlinking
   
user_schema = UserSchema()
users_schema = UserSchema(many=True)





@app.route("/users/")
def users():
    #row= db.session.query(User)
    all_users = User.query.all()
    results = users_schema.dump(all_users)
    return jsonify(results)





  @app.route("/users/<id>")
    def user_detail(id):
        user = User.query.get(id)
        results = user_schema.dump(user)
        return jsonify(results)
```